# SELECT from multiple cte with dynamic WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlperformance

I have a stored procedure which returns a list of records.

In one case (type=1), this will return the top 10 records based on page number.

In other case (type=2), this will return the all records.

The columns selected are same in both cases.

I am using 2 cte's to get the data required.

How can I implement the dynamic part which determines no. of records selected; with minimum performance impact.

Code blueprint

```
with cte1 as 
(
    SELECT ....
),
cte2 as 
(
    SELECT ....
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Col1) AS RowId,
    cte1.*, cte2.PlanName
FROM 
    cte1 
INNER JOIN
    cte2 ON cte2.Id = cte1.Id 
WHERE
    .....\*different code here*\
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried case inside WHERE. But I am worried about the performance. Will it be better to split the 2 processes into 2 sp's?

Comment: first, check for parameter sniffing issue, or you can put the execution plan to see what's happening, but till now, this question is off-topic because you don't have a problem because your code is working

Comment: @BudaGavril  Hi. the problem I'm facing is to limit the no. of records selected, if @type=1.. and select all if @type=2.  IF  can't be used since its after a cte. WIll case have a big impact on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `WHERE` condition like `where (RowId <=10 and @case=1) or @case=2`

Your query should look like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY col1) AS RowId, 
               cte1.*, 
               cte2.planname 
        FROM   cte1 
               INNER JOIN cte2 
                       ON cte2.id = cte1.id)t 
WHERE  ( rowid <= 10 
         AND @case = 1 ) 
        OR @case = 2
```

If `case=1` above code will return only 10 rows based on your `row_number()` else it will return all.

Answer (score 0):

use `union all`

```
with cte1 as (SELECT ....) ,

cte2 as (SELECT ....) select * from cte union all select * cte2
```

Comment: Hi.. How can I filter the no. of records selected? In type 1.. it should be 10 records; I type 2, all records to be selected

Comment: @needtoflow in cte 1 select top 10 recrds and in cte2 select all then merge by union all

Comment: hi  I can't use select top 10 in cte;  I need all records in cte and then filter 10 records based on the page number selected by user in grid. This is type 1 case.